# Why keep pop up uialert even internet connection is good

Tags: ios, timeout, nsurlconnection

I had put this request in `ViewDidLoad` but even i have a good internet connection it still pop up `UIAlertView` non stop and didn't return any value. is it i need to put the timeout longer time?

```
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:URL];
__unsafe_unretained ASIFormDataRequest *_request = request;

[request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
[request setPostValue:@"admin_request_user_join_group" forKey:@"tag"];
[request setPostValue:groupID forKey:@"group_id"];
[request setPostValue:userID forKey:@"poster_user_id"];
[request setPostValue:targetUserID forKey:@"target_user_id"];
[request setDelegate:self];
[request setTimeOutSeconds:30.0];
[request setShouldAttemptPersistentConnection:NO];
[request startAsynchronous];
[request setCompletionBlock:^(void){
    NSInteger responseCode = [_request responseStatusCode];

    if (responseCode == 200 || responseCode == 201 || responseCode == 202)
    {
        NSMutableDictionary *response = (NSMutableDictionary *)[[_request responseString] JSONValue];

        NSInteger success = [[response objectForKey:@"success"] integerValue];

        if (success == 1) {
            NSMutableDictionary *dict = [myFriendArray objectAtIndex:sender.tag];
            [dict setObject:@"0" forKey:@"join_group_status"];

            [myFriendArray replaceObjectAtIndex:sender.tag withObject:dict];

            NSIndexPath *rowToReload = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:sender.tag inSection:0];
            NSArray* rowsToReload = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:rowToReload, nil];



        }
    }
}];

[request setFailedBlock:^(void){
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Connection Failed" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"CONNECTION_FAILED", nil)] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];


}];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:URL];
__unsafe_unretained ASIFormDataRequest *_request = request;

[request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
[request setPostValue:@"admin_request_user_join_group" forKey:@"tag"];
[request setPostValue:groupID forKey:@"group_id"];
[request setPostValue:userID forKey:@"poster_user_id"];
[request setPostValue:targetUserID forKey:@"target_user_id"];
[request setDelegate:self];
[request setTimeOutSeconds:30.0];
[request setShouldAttemptPersistentConnection:NO];
[request startAsynchronous];
[request setCompletionBlock:^(void){
    NSInteger responseCode = [_request responseStatusCode];

    if (responseCode == 200 || responseCode == 201 || responseCode == 202)
    {
        NSMutableDictionary *response = (NSMutableDictionary *)[[_request responseString] JSONValue];

        NSInteger success = [[response objectForKey:@"success"] integerValue];

        if (success == 1) {
            NSMutableDictionary *dict = [myFriendArray objectAtIndex:sender.tag];
            [dict setObject:@"0" forKey:@"join_group_status"];

            [myFriendArray replaceObjectAtIndex:sender.tag withObject:dict];

            NSIndexPath *rowToReload = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:sender.tag inSection:0];
            NSArray* rowsToReload = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:rowToReload, nil];



        }
    }
[request setFailedBlock:^(void){
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Connection Failed" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"CONNECTION_FAILED", nil)] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];


}];


}];
```

This might help you

Comment: it showed a warning on setfailedblock request with "Capturing 'request' strongly in this block is likely to lead to a retain cycle."

Comment: moved "}];" after the setfailedblock is that mean it wont display the uialert if there is internet connection. how about if dun have any internet connection?

Comment: Use __weakself  for avoid retain cycle.....
And mark as correct answers if you think that was correct answers.